# Difference between Firebug Net Panel and custom console timer for window.load time

Tags: javascript, optimization, firebug

Why is there a difference between the `window.load` time reported by the net panel in Firebug and a custom timer setup like this (using jquery just for example but easily done without it):

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
$(window).load(function(){
    console.log((new Date().getTime() - start)*1000, 'sec');
});
```

For my particular document i got ~2 secs on the timer and ~5 secs in the net panel.

Answer (score 0):

Because this code

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
```

starts executing after some time your page started to load.

To start this code browser needs to load everything before it (html, css, scripts, probably images if this code is in body not in head).

Comment: I put it first thing in the head just to avoid that :), that's why it's strange. Even so it might not be executed before other files are downloaded.

Comment: But browser still needs to make connection to web-server and get some html from it to start executing script. Don't you have screenshot of loading diagram?